# Poisson random variables converging to zero

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, statistical-inference

I need help to prove if $X_n$ are Poisson random variables with parameter $1/n$, then $X_n\xrightarrow{\mathbb P} 0$. What is the standard method to solve this kind of question?

Comment: I think you mean *Pois**s**on* random variables

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

$$\mathbb P\left\{|X_n|>\varepsilon \right\}\leq \frac{1}{\varepsilon^2 }\mathbb E[X_n^2].$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What's the name of this inequality?

Comment: Why do you need a name ? This is a rather obvious inequality :-) $$\varepsilon \boldsymbol 1_{\{|X_n|>\varepsilon \}}\leq 
 |X_n|\boldsymbol 1_{\{|X_n|>\varepsilon \}}\leq |X_n|$$ and take the square...

Comment: A question about the notation: What does $\boldsymbol 1_{\{|X_n|>\varepsilon \}}$ mean?

Comment: @user42912: $\boldsymbol 1_A(x):= \begin{cases}1&x\in A\\ 0&x\notin A\end{cases}$

Answer (score 1):

an alterntative way is to observe that the MGF limit of your sequence is

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}e^{\frac{1}{n}(e^t-1)}=e^0$$

We immediately recognize a MGF of a degenerate distribution in $x_0=0$

As the sequence converge in distribution to a constant, it converges also in probability

Answer (score 0):

Using [Markov's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality) and the fact that the support of a Poisson random variable is non-negative, we have:

$$P(|X_n|\ge \epsilon)\le \frac{\mathbb{E}(|X_n|)}{\epsilon}=\frac{\mathbb{E}(X_n)}{\epsilon}=\frac{1}{n\epsilon}\to 0$$

as $n$ goes to infinity.